# Awk/Sed commands find and replace pattern

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk

I have a file with data like the following. `xyz` can be anything, so I want to replace it.

```
variable "azure_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "xyz"
      size         = "max"
      vpc          = "azure_spoke1_vnet"
    },
  }
}

variable "google_spoke_gateways" {
  default = {
    spoke1 = {
      name         = "xyz"
      size         = "max"
      vpc          = "azure_spoke1_vnet"
    },
  }
}
```

I just want to replace value of `variable azure_spoke_gateways`'s `name`. The desired output is:

```
  variable "azure_spoke_gateways" {
      default = {
        spoke1 = {
          name         = "MYSTRING"
          size         = "max"
          vpc          = "azure_spoke1_vnet"
        },
      }
    }
```

Comment: I feel your pain. Pretty frustrating to see these data formats that are _almost_ standard JSON or Tcl, but slightly different.

Comment: @glennjackman  into this mess from last 1 week :( feeling like crying now

Comment: @Shahroz Pervaz been a good 3 month now and not a single vote, feel like crying now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you can parse line by line on simpler formats, as long as you keep track of the subsection.

```
awk '  
  match($0,/variable "([^"]+)" {/,m) {  
    v = m[1]  
  }  
  $1 ~ /name/{  
    if(v == "azure_spoke_gateways") {  
      gsub(/"[^"]+"$/, "\"MYSTRING\"", $0)  
    }  
  } 1' data
```

You could also make it as a script file.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

match($0,/variable "([^"]+)" {/,m) {
    v = m[1]
}
v == "google_spoke_gateways" {
    if($1 == "name"){
        gsub(/"[^"]+"$/, "\"MYSTRING\"", $0)
    }
    if($1 == "size") {
        gsub(/"[^"]+"$/, "\"min\"", $0)
    }
    if($1 == "vpc") {
        gsub(/"[^"]+"$/, "\"google_spoke1_vnet\"", $0)
    }
} 1
```

And you run the script like this.

```
awk -f script.awk < data
```

Comment: if I want to change   vpc , size  as well ?

Comment: Sure just make another like name, `v` keeps track of variable section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Perl command:

```bsh
perl -0777 -pe 's/(variable "azure_spoke_gateways".*?name *= *)".*?"/\1"MYSTRING"/gs' input_file
```

It will replace whatever is inside `""` (not only `xyz`) for `name` with `MYSTRING`.

If you want to only replace `xyz`, use:

```bsh
perl -0777 -pe 's/(variable "azure_spoke_gateways".*?name *= *)"xyz"/\1"MYSTRING"/gs' input_file
```

To change `input_file` in-place, add the `-i` flag right before `input_file`.

Comment: I ran this command  like this in bash script  `perl -e 's/(variable "azure_spoke_gateways".*?name += ").*?(")/\1"MYSTRING"\2/gs'  /variables.tf`  and its not working

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz Run the command as I gave it above, with `-0777 -pe`.

Comment: still not working :(

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz It works for your sample. Can you add another sample for which it is not working? I also made some minor change, please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the blocks are separated by one or more blank lines, you could do something like this with awk's *paragraph mode*:

```
 gawk -vRS= -vmystring='"MYSTRING"' '
   BEGIN {OFS=FS="\n"} 
   $1 ~ /"azure_spoke_gateways"/ {
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
       if($i ~ /^[[:blank:]]*name[[:blank:]]*=/) sub(/"xyz"/,mystring,$i)
     }
   } {printf $0 RT}
 ' file
```

If the order of fields is known and fixed, you can dispense with the loop to locate the `name` field.

If you don't have GNU awk (gawk) then you can use regular awk but won't be able to make use of `RT` to resubstitute the actual record separators - you'd need to set `ORS` to something fixed like `\n\n`.

Comment: xyz is unknow string :( I dont have any idea what it would be

Comment: @ShahrozPervaz in that case, you may replace `/"xyz"/` with `/"[^"]*"/` in the `sub`

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^variable "azure_spoke_gateways"\s*{$/ , /^\s*name[^=]*=\s*"[^"]*"$/{
    s/\(name[^=]*=\).*/\1 "MYSTRING"/; }' infile
```